# Merge all local pull requests to local master

Tags: git, github

How do I merge all the local pull requests to the local branch:'master'?
I have Git and GitHub Desktop installed...
I got them by doing:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = https://*************7.git
    fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

in the .git/config file

Then running  `$ git fetch origin`
after I selected my repository with "cd" in cmd
They are saved like this:

```
*[new ref] refs/pull/1/head -> origin/pr/1
*[new ref] refs/pull/100/head -> origin/pr/100
*[new ref] refs/pull/102/head -> origin/pr/102
*[new ref] refs/pull/103/head -> origin/pr/103
*[new ref] refs/pull/104/head -> origin/pr/10
```

...
I just don't feel like merging 115 pull request manually.

Comment: Looks like automatically merging PRs is still a beta feature for GitHub, but this page might help: https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/automatically-merging-a-pull-request

Comment: automating this seems _problematic_ at least...